# How to implement the router(express) inside class constructor in a separate js file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to do some optimization in a javascript project, I have two files ClassA.js and the appi.js. In the ClassA.js i have the functions that I use for different manipulations and in the api.js I call them via the requests I get. But now I want to move the http methonds inside a javascript class constructor. Like in the following code and I get some errors(and i dont think i got it in the right way, I am a beginner in Nodejs).

Some of the errors are like:
Router.use() requires middleware function but got a Object
And after i made some other changes i get 
Json.path is not a function(on my server.js)

```
//I have imported(required) everything I need, express, router etc..

function classA(filename, jsonparser, url)
{
        this.filename = filename;
        this.jsonparser = jsonparser;
        this.url = url;
        router.get(url,function(req,res{classA.prototype.functionA(req,res)});
        router.post(url, function(req,res){classA.prototype.functionB(req,res)});
}
classA.prototype.functionA = function(req,res)
{//Does something}
classA.prototype.functionA = function(req,res)
{//Does something}

module.exports = {
router:router,
classA:classA
}

//In the api.js
I want the following
let a = require('../ClasA.js');
let ObjA = new a.classA("filenamepath",JsonObject, "URL");
let express = require('express');
let app = express();
app.use(a.router);

module.exports = router

//Server
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');

const api = require('./server/routes/api');
const port = 3000;

const app = express();
//Some other code
app.use('/',api);
app.get('*',(req,res)=>{
    res.sendfile(path.json(__dirname,'dist/index.html'));
});
//listen function
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Describe the errors you get and what you have investigated regarding those errors.

Comment: @JeroenHeier I uploaded the question.

Comment: This doesn't even look like proper Javascript syntax: `router.get(url,function(req,res{classA.prototype.functionA(req,res)});`.  What are you trying to do there?

Comment: @jfriend00 originally the http methods were implemented in the api.js(and worked fine), but i had a request to move the http methods inside the constructor and send them the url and other parameters via the constructor. Ps whats why i wrote I dont know if it is right implemented. So any tips/ideas? Basically i need to implement the http methods(post, get, delete) in another file(inside a class constructor) and call them(use them) form the api

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand what you're asking.  You will have to describe what you're trying to accomplish and exactly what error you encounter in more detail for anyone to be able to help.  Also your code contains what looks like invalid syntax which I pointed out, but you didn't even respond to.

Comment: @jfriend00. is it possible to use router.get inside a constructor?

Comment: @Sken - It is possible.  `router.get()` is just a function call, but you should only be making a particular `router.get()` call ONCE so it would be odd to be putting it in a constructor unless you never created more than one of those objects or unless the arguments to `router.get()` were different every time.  You don't show any real code that uses your `classA` so it's hard to advise whether what you're doing is OK or not.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks man I found a  solution!